# Getting more than one line from .txt file C++

Tags: c++

I want to take more than one line from the data.txt file. I am able to take only the first one. I tried using while loop but it seems that I don't know how to use it in this case.

Edited with while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int zapis()
{
    fstream file;
    string text;

    file.open("data.txt", ios::app);
    cout << "Type in text that you would like to store: ";
    getline(cin, text);
    file << text << endl;
    file.close();

    return 0;
}

int odczyt()
{
    fstream file;
    string line;
    int nr_lini = 1;

    file.open("data.txt", ios::in);
    if(file.good()==false)
    {
        cout << "Error occured!";
    }
    else
    {
        while(getline(file, line))
           {
               getline(file, line);
               cout << line;
           }
    }
    file.close();

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    zapis();
    odczyt();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do loop between `file.open` and `file.close`

Comment: please show your attempt with the `while` loop. It is much easier to help when we know what problem you are facing

Comment: see also: [mcve]

Comment: Have you done any research? It should be very easy to find examples of how to read lines from a file.

Answer (score 2):

Why call getline **twice** in your loop? Also pay attention to the semi-colons

```
 while(getline(file, line));
                           ^
```

What do you think the semi-colon there does?

This is correct

```
while (getline(file, line))
{
    cout << line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, just loop through the file. Also, you could make the function `void`, as it always `returns 0`, with you not doing anything with the return value.

```
void odczyt(){

    fstream file;
    string line;

    file.open("data.txt", ios::in);
    if(!file.good())
    {
        cout << "Error occured!";
    }
    else
    {
        while(getline(file, line);) {  // while text file still has lines, you write the line and read next
            cout << line;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to delete this int after my previous tries. I am getting this error: error: could not convert 'line' from 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'bool'.